# Update Code & Rebuild Jar File in IntelliJ Does Not Add File. What am I Missing?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Usually when I build jars, I take the following steps:

File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts

I do that only once then I create the jar file overview there whenever I want to update it.

Then, when I want to build the jar, I goto

Build -> Build Artifacts

Then I will select Build Jar

[image]

Sometimes this will add something into my project folder, sometimes it doesn't. I don't know why sometimes it is consistent and sometimes it isn't. I basically just want to update code then have a new jar I can copy and paste somewhere. I wonder if there is an easier way?

Comment: Can you provide more context, please? What creates this file (the JAR or IntelliJ)? Where do you want the file created?

Comment: well that's how I create the jar above, but sometimes it just doesn't get created, when I go to build artifact as shown in the screenshot and click on build, there are no updated jars in my directory, just my original one i made.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. New Questions: Assuming the JAR is named the same as the last time you built it, how are you determining that it isn't the updated JAR. Also, what directory are you looking in to find you're freshly built JAR?

Comment: thanks. i might have been looking in the wrong place. i was looking at the folders last updated time and i think i was not checking in the out folder. i'm not sure either way, but it seemed to work this time when i tried today so i might have missed it before, i'm not sure. lol. feel free to post an ansewr and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are(were) looking in the wrong directory for your built JAR.

By default, IntelliJ stores it's builds and outputs in the `out/` directory (found at the root of you project directory).

Inside `out/` you'll find the following 2 directories:

- `production/`
  This is where all you compiled classes are deployed along with any other files pulled from your `src/` directory.
- `artifacts/`
  This directory only appears if you've set up your project to generate an artifact (which you have).

If you run that build command you've been running, a fresh JAR will be generated in:
`out/artifacts/<artifact_name>/<artifact_name>.jar`